# How to display Chinese with special font characters in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I have a piece of text that contains characters in special fonts. The characters in special fonts are displayed abnormally. If Chinese are included, Chinese will not come out. On Android, after setting the font on iOS, Chinese can be displayed normally, but special characters still cannot be displayed.

eg:

```
中文aaa111
```

[image]

Special characters cannot be displayed and can be ignored. How should the affected Chinese be displayed correctly?

```
Text(
  '中文aaa111',
  style: TextStyle(fontFamilyFallback: ["PingFang SC", "Heiti SC"]),
),
```

Comment: Add the font to your project and then specify the fontFamily name .

Comment: Quoting the font file of special characters can indeed solve the problem of special characters. My question is how can the Chinese contained in the text be displayed normally without introducing the font file, and the display problem of special characters can be ignored.

Comment: Add Code instead of images

Comment: @Prashant Text(
  '中文aaa111',
  style: TextStyle(fontFamilyFallback: ["PingFang SC", "Heiti SC"]),
),